# Selecting indexes of elements with a common property in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and would like to obtain the indexes of the elements that verify a common property. For example, suppose the array is `np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])`, and I want to have the indexes of all elements equal to 1, so the output would be `[0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 14]`.

I have defined the following procedure

```
def find_indexes(A):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] == 1:
            res.append(i)
    return res
```

Is there a more "pythonesque" way of doing this? More specifically, I am wondering if there is something similar to boolean indexing:

```
A[A>=1]
```

that would return the indexes of the elements rather than the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
  import numpy as np
  x = np.array(np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
  indices, = np.where(x == 1)
  print(indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
arr = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
print np.where(arr == 1)
(array([ 0,  4,  5,  8, 10, 14]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension for pure python:

ar = [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == 1]